# Unexpected error when trying to concatenate dataframes with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, categorical-data

I've got two dataframes df1 and df2 that look like this:

```
#df1
                    counts    freqs
categories                 
automatic           13      0.40625
manual              19      0.59375

#df2

                    counts   freqs
categories                     
Straight Engine      18     0.5625
V engine             14     0.4375
```

Could anyone explain why `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)` will not give me this:

```
                    counts   freqs
categories                     
automatic               13  0.40625
manual                  19  0.59375 
Straight Engine         18  0.5625
V engine                14  0.4375
```

---

**Here is what I've tried:**

1 - Using `pd.concat()`

I'm suspecting that the way I've built these dataframes may be the source of the issue.
And here is how I've ended up with these particular dataframes:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
from pydataset import data # pip install pydataset to get datasets from R

# load data 
df_mtcars = data('mtcars')

# change dummyvariables to more describing variables:
df_mtcars['am'][df_mtcars['am'] == 0] = 'manual'
df_mtcars['am'][df_mtcars['am'] == 1] = 'automatic' 
df_mtcars['vs'][df_mtcars['vs'] == 0] = 'Straight Engine'
df_mtcars['vs'][df_mtcars['vs'] == 1] = 'V engine'

# describe categorical variables
df1 = pd.Categorical(df_mtcars['am']).describe()
df2 = pd.Categorical(df_mtcars['vs']).describe()
```

I understand that 'categories' is what is causing the problems here since `df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)` raises this error:

> TypeError: categories must match existing categories when appending

But it confuses me that this is ok:

```
# code
df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

# output:
                 counts       freqs  counts   freqs
categories                                      
automatic          13.0     0.40625     NaN     NaN
manual             19.0     0.59375     NaN     NaN
Straight Engine     NaN         NaN    18.0  0.5625
V engine            NaN         NaN    14.0  0.4375
```

2 - Using `df.append()` raises the same error as `pd.concat()`

3 - Using `pd.merge()` sort of works, but I'm losing the indexes:

```
# Code
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer')

# Output
   counts    freqs
0      13  0.40625
1      19  0.59375
2      18  0.56250
3      14  0.43750
```

3 - Using `pd.concat()` on transposed dataframes

Since `pd.concat()` worked with `axis = 0` I thought I would get there using transposed dataframes.

```
# df1.T 
categories  automatic    manual
counts       13.00000  19.00000
freqs         0.40625   0.59375

# df2.T
categories  Straight Engine  V engine
counts              18.0000   14.0000
freqs                0.5625    0.4375
```

But still no success:

```
# code
df_con = pd.concat([df1.T, df2.T], axis = 1)

>>> TypeError: categories must match existing categories when appending
```

By the way, what  I was hoping for here is this:

```
categories  automatic    manual Straight Engine  V engine
counts       13.00000  19.00000         18.0000   14.0000
freqs         0.40625   0.59375          0.5625    0.4375
```

Still kind of works with `axis = 0` though:

```
# code  
df_con = pd.concat([df1.T, df2.T], axis = 0)

# Output
categories  automatic    manual  Straight Engine  V engine
counts       13.00000  19.00000              NaN       NaN
freqs         0.40625   0.59375              NaN       NaN
counts            NaN       NaN          18.0000   14.0000
freqs             NaN       NaN           0.5625    0.4375
```

But that is still far from what I'm trying to accomplish.

Now I'm thinking that it would be possible to strip the 'category' info from df1 and df2, but I haven't been able to find out how to do that yet.

Thank you for any other suggestions!

Comment: this is because you are having categorcal index, if you reset your index and perform concat it works well. for concat operation it based on index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index()],ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
        categories  counts    freqs
0        automatic      13  0.40625
1           manual      19  0.59375
2  Straight Engine      18  0.56250
3         V engine      14  0.43750
```

To get again category as index follow this,

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index()],ignore_index=True).set_index('categories')
```

Output:

```
                 counts    freqs
categories                      
automatic            13  0.40625
manual               19  0.59375
Straight Engine      18  0.56250
V engine             14  0.43750
```

for more details follow [this docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)